# runtime error for binary tree node member assignment

Tags: c++, struct, binary-tree, nodes

I am writing a C++ program that implements a `Binary Search Tree (BST)`. So, I started off implementing a binary tree node as a `struct`. Since a binary tree node contains two `pointers` to other binary tree nodes, the struct includes pointers to variables of that struct type. For this, I understand that a forward declaration of the struct is needed. I've done that. Yet, I get a run-time error for the simple program below which does nothing but assign a value to a member of said struct. I don't understand why. Please let me know the reason.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct t_node;

struct t_node
{
       int data;
       t_node* left;
       t_node* right;
};

int main()
{
    t_node *root;
    root->data = 2;

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

I am using `Dev-C++ 4.9.9.2`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to alocate memory for your node. Use `new`:

```
t_node* root = new t_node();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
t_node *root;
root->data = 2;
```

Is bad. You are derecerencing an uninitialised pointer.

```
t_node *root = new t_node;
root->data = 2
```

Will allocate memory for your node, and fix your issue.